# Make long header files compile once?

Tags: g++, catch2

Alright so I'm using the "Catch2" framework for C++ Unit Testing and in my "testMain.cpp" (Doesn't matter) I include the single header version of it `#include "Catch.hpp"`.

The problem is every time I write just a small test, I have to compile the program in order to see the outputs again. But the single header is something like 70000 lines and it takes FOREVER.

I understand that with source files you can simply compile them into object files and after that link them. So if you are using the same source file for just linking there is no really a need to recompile it over again.

So the point of this question is, Is it possible to somehow compile the **Catch.hpp** file and just use it as a link after words? Or in order to slow it down do I have to get the multi-header version of the framework?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/slow-compiles.md ?

It is recommended to move the tests main function to a separate file, so that the compile intensive parts are only compiled once.